# Getting access token using MSAL fails

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, msal

I am developing an azure web app service called emailservice, which is supposed to communicate to a mailbox created in office365 exchange online. Suppose the user account for the mailbox is x @y-domain.com.

The webapp is suppose to retrieve messages form the inbox or sent messages. I have decided to use Microsoft graph api for this matter.

To be able to have successful call to graph API, I need to register the app on Azure. I have done that as well. Delegated access has been given and Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.send permission under graph has been granted by an admin. We are good on the consent side as well.
I am using MSAL to get the token.
`y

```
const authClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        authority: `${azureActiveDirectoryEndPoint}${tenantId}`,
    }
});
function getToken(): Promise<string> {
    return authClient.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
        scopes,
    }).then(authResult =>{
        if (!authResult) {
            throw new Error('Authentication failed!')
        }
        return authResult.accessToken;
    })
}
    async retrieveNewEmails() {
        

        const accessToken = await getToken();
        // some code
    }
```

I am currently testing this code on my local machine. My call to acquireTokenByClientCredential fails. I have few questions.

- Is this a correct method to call for my scenario in order to get accessToken
- If the method is correct, I think I am not setting the scope correctly
  I have tried few different scopes.
  I think I do not have proper understanding of scopes and what it should include
  I know it should include the end point which is 'https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/
  I think it should include user account as well. I guess it should include  x@y-domain.com as well
  I am not sure it should have any indication of the permissions or not like Mail.ReadWrite
- Here is what I have tried and the error messages
  const scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/x@y-domain.com'];
  no token is generated and it prompts me with error saying “ERROR [ExceptionsHandler]
  invalid_scope: 1002012 - [2024-03-13 22:26:25Z]: AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope
  https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/me is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope
  value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI). “

  ```
      Why /.default?

   const scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/ x@y-domain.com'/.default'];
         No token is generated and it prompts me with error saying “ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
         invalid_resource: 500011 - [2024-03-13 22:21:50Z]: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named 
         https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/x was not found in the tenant named * . This can happen if 
         the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by 
         any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.”
  ```

I would appreciate if you would help me to find what is missing.

As mentioned I tried two different scopes above.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by changing the scope to `https://graph.microsoft.us/.default`. You may find this link helpful about understanding scopes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scopes-oidc.

Comment: The link is indeed a very good reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Your scope should be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default while generating token with client credentials flow and grant permissions of **Application** type.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted API permissions of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I used below **modified** code to generate access token and used it to list messages like this:

```js
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const axios = require('axios');

const tenantId = "tenantId";
const clientId = "appId";
const clientSecret = "secret";
const scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]; // Microsoft Graph scope

const authClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: {
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
    }
});

async function getToken() {
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await authClient.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
            scopes
        });
        if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.accessToken) {
            return tokenResponse.accessToken;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Failed to acquire access token');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Error retrieving access token: ' + error);
    }
}

async function listMessages(accessToken, userUPN) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${userUPN}/messages`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });
        const messages = response.data.value;
        console.log("\nMessages:");
        messages.forEach(message => {
            console.log(`- ${message.subject}`);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving messages:', error.message);
    }
}

async function retrieveEmails() {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getToken();
        console.log('Access Token:', accessToken);
        const userUPN = "sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"; 
        await listMessages(accessToken, userUPN);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving emails:', error.message);
    }
}

retrieveEmails();
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Few questions. If I have Mail.ReadWrite, do I still need Mail.Read? Moreover when do you run ur app, on cloud or local machine? I got app registration with app only access and with Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.Send permissions. My code is supposed to send an email but when I run it on local machine, it complains "[Nest] 11088  - 03/15/2024, 8:28:04 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to send email:{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationError","message":"AADSTS900382: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request."

Comment: If Mail.ReadWrite is given, there is no need to add Mail.Read as it'll included in it. Regarding the error, could you include endpoints screenshot of your app Overview page from Portal by editing your question to check whether you are using any cross cloud?

Comment: I fixed the issue and did not get a chance to mention here. I was mixing commercial and gov cloud. That is why it was complaining about cross cloud request.